# Set netgear router to AP mode cannot get in web interface

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I have two netgear routers:

- Netgear fvs336gv2 (professional router)(192.168.1.1)
- Netgear wndr4500v2 (consumer router)(192.168.1.103)

The pro router is the main router fvs336gv2 (192.168.1.1) and I have plugged an ethernet cable from a port of the pro router into the internet port of the consumer router (192.168.1.103) When I have wifi connection to the consumer router (access  point mode) I have a perfect internet connection the only downside is that I cannot get into the web interface of the consumer router (access point)

When I go to http://routerlogin.net it gives me a default website of one of our running internal webservers (I forwarded port 80 in the main router) When I go to http://192.168.1.103 i get the same thing.

In the pro routers webinterface (192.168.1.1) I can see by the mac address that the ip ending with 103 is of the access point. When I plug an ethernet cable in the accesspoint 'lan' ports I also cannot enter the webinterface.

It seems (to me) that when you set a Netgear router to AP-mode, it becomes unmanageable. I have no idea how to fix this. The option to restore access to the webinterface is reset the accesspoint, but then it will be a router again with dhcp etc. and I want it to function as accesspoint (because the new pro-router has no wifi and my co-wokers macbook air has no ethernet port)

**edit** I identified the router which was set to accesspoint by looking in the connected lan clients of the pro/main router and searching for it's mac address

**edit 2** the steps I took to get it to ap-mode are similar to http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/23814

Comment: Configuration is fine. Netgear website confirms that in order to set the old router as AP mode, you need to connect it to the internet port. Setting it to ap mode disables nat and the dhcp server, making the old router act like a regular dhcp client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, webinterface was unavailable (somehow) but you can access it by installing Genie http://www.netgear.com/home/discover/apps/genie.aspx
and add the ip of the access point manually

Comment: If you plugged it into the WAN port on the consumer router, you may want to try one of the other ports instead.  Those are LAN ports, since you're establishing an AP instead of a new NAT network, your consumer router and pro router will need to be on the same subnet.  The WAN port may work differently -- it might think it's still an internet connection.

Comment: @trpt4him identified my issue.  The confusion arises from the instructions for initial setup.  It makes it seem like the router will determine that you have a network already and configure it for an AP, but apparently this is only if you use the LAN port.

Comment: Yeah, and what do you do if you don't know the IP address since the router was set to determine it's own IP via DHCP? Now it's basically inaccessible unless I try every single IP on the subnet. Grrr... Netgear!

Answer (score 0):

If the Netgear device is configured as an Access Point, try http://aplogin.net rather than routerlogin.net. Assuming your device is connected to the WiFi on that AP, then this should resolve to the IP address of the AP and allow access to the Web UI in the browser (watch out for browser caching).

```
$ nslookup aplogin.net
Server:  cache1.service.virginmedia.net
Address:  194.168.4.100

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    aplogin.net
Addresses:  192.168.0.42
          192.168.0.42
```