# Netgear DGN2200v4 serving my modem's DHCP, cannot access web interface

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

### Specs

http://support.netgear.com/product/DGN2200v4

```
Netgear N300 Wireless ADSL2+ Modem Router with Ethernet WAN
DGN2200v4
Ports: ADSL       WAN/4   3   2   1   USB   Power
```

### Question

When connecting the DGN2200 to my modem, I am immediately unable to connect to its web interface (192.168.0.1 or routerlogin.net)

The internet actually works fine.  However, it looks like connected devices are served on the separate modem's DHCP.

After disconnecting, doing a hard reset with the reset button, and reconnecting, I get the same results.

The only way to connect to the router web interface again is by connecting it directly to my computer via Ethernet, and then doing a hard reset. After this, I can connect to it either via the Ethernet or Wireless so long as it's not plugged in to my modem.

Why is this happening?

### Notes

I understand that the DGN2200 is a modem/router and ideally I shouldn't need an external modem. The thing is, I'm having the same error both in connecting the modem/router directly to my DSL line (regardless of whether it's configured correctly or not) and connecting the modem's Ethernet to the dual specified WAN/LANPort4.

Since the DGN2200 is in factory default settings, it shouldn't be in AP mode (which would make it use the DHCP of the external modem for everything). It also should have the DHCP on automatically.

Also, it's worth noting that I have not seen the internet light on the DGN2200 light up at all.

This router is the most puzzling that I have dealt with in a while. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest checking the router's configuration using the Netgear Genie app.

Comment: Instead of the web interface... Yeah, but what does the Genie app connect to on the router? If it's port 80, that won't work either. I'll try it anyway...

Comment: Looks like that doesn't matter though... http://superuser.com/a/869535/222612